# Js Array gives null

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, null, onclick

Why Array gives null outside script onclick event in htm5? The others variables works correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Array</title>
  <script>
    var list = new Array("andrea", "matteo", "marco");
    var x = "andrea";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="alert(list[0]);">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if `list` is named almost anything else, the code works - I know there are some variable names that behave this way, not sure what is special about `list` though

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the `input` HTMLElement object has a [`list` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#list), so JS is assuming you're trying to access a property of the current element, not your globally-scoped variable.

A quick fix to this would be to access the variable via `window.list` to be explicit about the instance you're trying to access:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Array</title>
  <script>
    var list = new Array("andrea", "matteo", "marco");
    var x = "andrea";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="alert(window.list[0]);">
</body>
</html>
```

Better still, you should avoid using `onX` attributes wherever possible. Use unobtrusive event handlers bound in JS. You can also use this method to avoid using global variables:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Array</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const list = ["andrea", "matteo", "marco"];
      
      document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log(list[0]);
      }); 
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="click">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but i don't understand why the others variables, even the objects work without 'window.'

Comment: it's to do with the name of the variable `list` ... nothing to do with scope

Comment: @JaromandaX you're correct, I tried my first solution and made an assumption from there, my bad. I'm not sure why this is happening yet, as `list` isn't a reserved word.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I know, it's really odd!!

Comment: @JaromandaX found the problem - `input` Element object has a `list` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#list

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - nice!! That was really annoying me!